# Regex is matching all combinations

Tags: regex

I have the following text below. How do I write the regex to capture all text related to `REQ_XXX`?

This is my expression `.*(REQ_.*)\|`, but it captures `|3 |4 |5`. I just want it to stop after the first `|` it sees.

[image]

Comment: I think you should delete and post in Stackoverflow.

Comment: If we can answer it here, it should be fine. RegEx is perhaps a grey area between coding and application work.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

```
.*(REQ_.*?)\|
```

The trick is `?` tells preceding `.*` to stop as early as possible. This way the first `|` that follows terminates the scope of `.*`. This is exactly what you want.

My old answer is below. It works well but I think the above is The Right Way.

---

Old answer:

`.*` matches (almost) everything, including `|`. Use `[^|\n]*` to match everything but `|` and newline.

```
.*(REQ_[^|]*)\|
```

`\n` is needed because pure `[^|]*` could span its match over multiple lines. I guess you don't want this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
.*(REQ_[^|]*)\|
```

The "|" character will be exclude.

Comment: Consider adding some reference supporting what you state as well.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the solutions are already posted in other answers, I'm giving a summary here.

You can follow multiple approaches here, you need to decide based on your needs which one you use:

1. give a positive list of characters appearing in your code:
   `.*(REQ_[\w]+)[\s]*\|`

   - in this case `[\w]+` matches all word characters (letters, numbers and "_")
   - whitespaces before `|` are not included in your captured result (`[\s]*` is out of the brackets)
2. give a negative list of characters, where you want your regex to stop:
   `.*(REQ_[^|]+)\|`
3. use lazy match to stop at first possibility:
   `.*(REQ_.+?)\|`

Answer (score 0):

If `REQ_` is allways followed by word characters, you can simply use `REQ_w+` or if you don't want to match `ABCREQ_123`, use a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html): `\bREQ_\w+`.

[See in action](https://regex101.com/r/mRaNs2/1)